VBA Loop Print to PDF
Is there a way to not print the pdf if I enter the Code/Reference to Column B and today is Saturday and the Bank from Column G is PNB it will not loop to print the pdf instead just print the other if not PNB and saturday today. This is my codes:
Sub PrintPDF()
    Dim WSDATA As Worksheet
    Dim WSFormat As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Batch As String
    Dim fname As Variant
    Dim exportRange As Range
    
    
    'Path = "D:\Desktop\TEST\"

    Set WSDATA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set WSFormat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DV Format")
    Set exportRange = WSFormat.Range("$A$1:$AD$50")
    
    Path = WSDATA.Range("C3").Value
    Batch = WSDATA.Range("C2").Value
    
    LastRow = WSDATA.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 5 To LastRow
        Code = WSDATA.Range("B" & i)
        
        If Code <> "" Then
            Bank = WSDATA.Range("G" & i)
            fname = Code & " " & Bank
        
            SDate = WSDATA.Range("D" & i).Value
            If SDate = "" Then
                SDate = UCase(Format((Date - 1), "MMMMDD.YYYY"))
            Else
                SDate = Replace(Replace(UCase(SDate), " ", ""), ",", ".")
            End If
            
            'AMOUNT
            WSFormat.Range("W16").Value = WSDATA.Range("C" & i).Value
            'PURPOSE
            WSFormat.Range("B16").Value = WSDATA.Range("E" & i).Value
            'BName
            WSFormat.Range("B12").Value = WSDATA.Range("F" & i).Value
            'Bank
            WSFormat.Range("M13").Value = WSDATA.Range("G" & i).Value
            'AccountName
            WSFormat.Range("N12").Value = WSDATA.Range("H" & i).Value
            'AccountNumber
            WSFormat.Range("R13").Value = WSDATA.Range("I" & i).Value
            'ModeOfPayment
            WSFormat.Range("Z13").Value = WSDATA.Range("J" & i).Value
            'Company
            WSFormat.Range("E8").Value = WSDATA.Range("K" & i).Value
            'Department
            WSFormat.Range("E9").Value = WSDATA.Range("L" & i).Value
            'Date
            WSFormat.Range("W8").Value = WSDATA.Range("C1").Value
            
            'SAVE PDF
            exportRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:=Path & fname & " " & SDate & "-" & Batch, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

Im expecting if today is Saturday, If All Banks from Column G is PNB it will not loop to print the PDF.

And what is your question? What have you tried do include your checks? For checking the day of the week se e.g. weekday function

You can try this approach
Sub PrintPDF()
    Dim WSDATA As Worksheet
    Dim WSFormat As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Batch As String
    Dim fname As Variant
    Dim exportRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Code As String
    Dim Bank As String
    Dim SDate As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim allPNB As Boolean
    
    
    'Path = "D:\Desktop\TEST\"
    Set WSDATA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set WSFormat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DV Format")
    Set exportRange = WSFormat.Range("$A$1:$AD$50")
    
    Path = WSDATA.Range("C3").Value
    Batch = WSDATA.Range("C2").Value
    
    LastRow = WSDATA.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'CONDITION TO CHECK TODAY IS SATURDAY
    If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 6 Then
        ' LOOP TO CHECK PNB BANK
        For i = 5 To LastRow
            If WSDATA.Range("G" & i).Value <> "PNB" Then
                allPNB = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        
        If allPNB Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Normal printing process
    For i = 5 To LastRow
        Code = WSDATA.Range("B" & i)
        
        If Code <> "" Then
            Bank = WSDATA.Range("G" & i)
            fname = Code & " " & Bank
            
            SDate = WSDATA.Range("D" & i).Value
            If SDate = "" Then
                SDate = UCase(Format((Date - 1), "MMMMDD.YYYY"))
            Else
                SDate = Replace(Replace(UCase(SDate), " ", ""), ",", ".")
            End If
            
            ' AMOUNT
            WSFormat.Range("W16").Value = WSDATA.Range("C" & i).Value
            ' PURPOSE
            WSFormat.Range("B16").Value = WSDATA.Range("E" & i).Value
            ' BName
            WSFormat.Range("B12").Value = WSDATA.Range("F" & i).Value
            ' Bank
            WSFormat.Range("M13").Value = WSDATA.Range("G" & i).Value
            ' AccountName
            WSFormat.Range("N12").Value = WSDATA.Range("H" & i).Value
            ' AccountNumber
            WSFormat.Range("R13").Value = WSDATA.Range("I" & i).Value
            ' ModeOfPayment
            WSFormat.Range("Z13").Value = WSDATA.Range("J" & i).Value
            ' Company
            WSFormat.Range("E8").Value = WSDATA.Range("K" & i).Value
            ' Department
            WSFormat.Range("E9").Value = WSDATA.Range("L" & i).Value
            ' Date
            WSFormat.Range("W8").Value = WSDATA.Range("C1").Value
            
            ' SAVE PDF
            exportRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:=Path & fname & " " & SDate & "-" & Batch, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

